# Promise not resolving in Jasmine - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm trying to test a method that deletes an item from a list after user confirmation.

**Controller:**

```
app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', 'dataService', function($scope, $window, dataService) {
  var vm = this;

  vm.delete = function(id, index) {
    if($window.confirm('Are you sure?')) {
      dataService.deleteById(id).then(function() {
        vm.list.splice(index, 1)
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

**Sevice:**

```
app.service('dataService', ['$http', function($http) {
  this.deleteById = function(id) {
    return $http.delete('delete-item?id=' + id);
  };
}]);
```

**Test:**

```
describe('Testing RecipesController', function() {
  var scope, ctrl, dataServiceMock, q, deferred, window;

  beforeEach(function() {
    dataServiceMock = {
      deleteById: function() {
        deferred = q.defer();
        return deferred.promise;
      }
    };
  });

  beforeEach(function() {
    module('app');
    inject(function($rootScope, $controller, $q, $window) {
      q = $q;
      window = $window;
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      ctrl = $controller('mainCtrl', {
        $scope: scope,
        dataService: dataServiceMock
      });
    });
  });

  it('should delete recipe if the user clicked "OK"', function() {
    spyOn(window, 'confirm').and.returnValue(true);
    spyOn(dataServiceMock, 'deleteById').and.callThrough();

    var item= {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Shirt'
    };

    ctrl.list = ['Hat', 'Shirt'];
    ctrl.delete(item, 1);

    expect(dataServiceMock.deleteById).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(ctrl.list.length).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

I successfully mocked the confirm dialog and the delete method, and the test to check if the method been called even passes.
But, The promise.then() isn't working.
After I run the test I got this message "Expected 2 to be 1".

Comment: In order for promise chain to be executed, a digest should be started, e.g.  $rootScope.$digest()

Comment: I tried to use scope.$digest(), but I got the same results...

Comment: You are passing an object in the Id parameter, maybe you need to pass `ctrl.delete(item.id,1);`. Also verify the promise is resolving correctly, if the promise is been rejected it will not execute `vm.list.splice(index, 1)`.

Comment: `$rootScope.$digest()` and `scope.$digest()` are totally different things.

Comment: `ctrl.delete(item.id,1)` and `$rootScope.$digest()` are getting the same results as before.. I also tried to add an reject function that mimics the resolved function, but the result is still the same.

Comment: deleteById returns pending promise. Use `return q.resolve(...)` instead.

Comment: I tried `return q.resolve(true)` and also `q.resolve(true);` before the return, but nothing has changed...

Comment: My bad, I had to also invoke the $rootScope.digest(). Now it's working! Thank you very much (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see one thing for sure, which is that you never resolve or reject your promise in the data service mock. Try changing the mock to this:

```
beforeEach(function() {
  dataServiceMock = {
    deleteById: function() {
      deferred = q.defer();
      deferred.resolve({ /* whatever data you want to resolve with */ });
      return deferred.promise;
      // You could also shorten this whole mock function to just:
      //    return $q.resolve({ /* some data */ });
    }
  };
});
```

Also, don't forget to execute the `$digest()` function on the `$rootScope` at the end of your test... you're actually executing it on your controller's scope, NOT the root scope.

Hold onto the actual $rootScope object - change your `beforeEach` to:

```
var $rScope;

beforeEach(function() {
    module('app');
    inject(function($rootScope, $controller, $q, $window) {
      q = $q;
      window = $window;
      $rScope = $rootScope;
      ctrl = $controller('mainCtrl', {
        $scope: $rootScope.$new(),
        dataService: dataServiceMock
      });
    });
});
```

Then in your test, execute `$digest` on the root scope at the end:

```
it('should delete recipe if the user clicked "OK"', function() {
  // all your test codez...

  $rScope.$digest();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the deep explanation! it's working now (;

Comment: Although I checked it with `scope.$digest()` and it also did the trick.

Comment: That's good to know, but just in case you ever have more than one scope (for example, interaction between controllers... which is bad anyway) then you want to execute `$digest()` on the root.